# Schur functors for representations of the borel

Tags: rt.representation-theory, algebraic-groups

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Let's denote by $V_{std} = k^n$ the standard representation of $GL_n$. We know that every irreducible representation of $GL_n$ can be obtained by applying a schur functor to $V_{std}$.

Is a similar result known for indecomposable representations of $B$ the upper triangular Borel of $GL_n$ ? In particular if I denote by $0 \subset V_1 \subset ...\subset V_n = V_{std}$ the standard flag of $V_{std}$ then each $V_i$ is an indecomposable representation of $B$ and I strongly expect that every indecomposable representation of $B$ should be writable as some equivalent of a Schur functor applied to the $V_i$'s.

The reason I expect this is that it would give a very natural proof to the following well known result (with $X$ a scheme over $k$) that there is an equivalence of categories between monoidal, exact, faithfull and $k$-linear functors from the category of finite dimensional algebraic representations of $B$ to the category of vector bundles on $X$ and the category of rank $n$ vector bundles on $X$ with a complete flag. (But I already know how to prove this result and the Schur functors are really what i'm after).